# What are the slot machine odds in New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I know that [slot machines](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Slots) are generally a sucker's game, but they also have the highest potential payouts. That said, after fighting one at the Atomic Wrangler for the better part of an hour, I'm not even near breaking even, and the best spins I've seen have been two cherries.

Is there a list of the odds of each reward? Does it vary by casino? Also, has anyone ever actually seen a decent payout on the New Vegas slots without having a 10 Luck stat?

Comment: I've hit a 30k jackpot with 7 Luck. It took about 25 minutes of hitting the slot machine.

Comment: You "fight" slot machines? Literally?

Comment: @miva2: No, that was a figure of speech.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I've seen (and according to the strategy guide), they are all standard across casinos and the odds work just like a regular casino: you will lose over the long term.

The only way to win is by cheating (reloading a save) or with a high luck. At high luck (7 and above), if you get a "cricital hit" while slotting, you will automatically win. But even with a 9 luck, I had to cheat to gain back 10,000 lost!